# How to make aliases for Controller of my Laravel custom package

Tags: php, laravel

I'm on the way of creating a Laravel package for our internal use, that's why it's not in packagist, and not in `vendor/` directory. Instead it's in `packages/` directory - a custom directory of ours - a similar approach we used for [another package of our internal use](https://github.com/technovistalimited/notific/).

Issue is, in the blades from the package we used `action('MyPackageController@method')` to produce links. After publishing the view files to the application the current path of the views are like `resources/views/vendor/mypackage/one-directory/index.blade.php`.

With a global access to the controller it simply is working:

```php
action('\MyVendor\MyPackage\App\Controllers\MyPackageController@edit', ['id' => $item->id])
```

But issue is, when I'm trying to [impose aliases](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-class-aliases-in-package) for the controller[s], they are not working. In `config/app.php` aliases, I mentioned:

```
'XYZ' => MyVendor\MyPackage\App\Controllers\MyPackageController::class,
'ABC' => MyVendor\MyPackage\App\Controllers\MyPackageSecondController::class,
```

and in `index.blade.php` I tried using:

```
action('ABC@edit', ['id' => $item->id])
```

but it's not working. Because it's trying to find the controller in `App\Http\Controllers\`:

> **ErrorException (E_ERROR)**
>   Action App\Http\Controllers\ABC@edit not defined. (View: D:\laragon\www\test-laravel\resources\views\vendor\mypackage\one-directory\index.blade.php)

Aren't package controllers be aliased?

**PS.** I tried clearing all types of caching.

Comment: Do you have a service provider for your package?

Comment: Use named routes instead.

Comment: I don't really know laravel, but perhaps `\ABC@edit` would work? The error suggests that it's looking in the current namespace, the leading slash would put it in the global namespace, where the alias might be defined.

Comment: @MartinBean There's no documentation of using named route in [`action()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-action). Can you please suggest with code example?

Comment: @JensV `action('\ABC@edit')` won't and didn't work, I'm sorry. :(

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, off course. Without a service provider a package won't work, na?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam You’d used a named route _instead_ of `action()`: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes

Comment: @MartinBean that's _THE_ answer. Could you please add the comment as an answer? What I found is: the [`action()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-controller-actions) has its caveat, it cannot take other namespaces other than `App\Http\Controllers`. So [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) did it for me: `route('my_name', ['id' => $item->id]);`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As even after a long time, Martin Bean did not add any answer to the thread, here I'm posting one for future record:

As Martin Bean said in his comment:

> *You’d used a named route instead of [`action()`: laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes)*

What I found is: [`the action()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-controller-actions) has its own caveat, it cannot take other namespaces other than `App\Http\Controllers`. So [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) did it for me: `route('my_name', ['id' => $item->id]);`.

Thanks to Martin Bean for his clue.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to register your routes in the service provider of your package.

```php
boot() { 
    require __DIR__ . '/Http/routes.php';
}
```

`__DIR__` would point to the root of your package folder. This is assuming your routes are registered in your packages' Http directory. If this is done, make sure you use a unique name for your route and just call your action like so: 
`action="{{route-name}}"`

That's all you have to do.

Comment: The question is NOT about `<form action="">`. :(

Comment: if your routes are properly registered in your service provide be it a form action or not, it would work